# iPhone 4: Determine Calendar Event Date time

Tags: date, time, calendar, validation, iphone-4

i never tried to add/edit event the calendar. but from the documentation([What's New in iOS4](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/whats-new.html#api)), it is clear that we can add/edit event in calendar programmatically. So i just want to ask how can we get all event of particular day ? Basically i want to validate the time of all event for particular day.